# Plot3D showing nothing

Tags: plotting

I tried to plot `f(x,y) = cos(x + y) + sin a(x-y)` where 0<=a<=10. I used `Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"},ColorFunction -> GrayLevel]`and it's not working and I think it's because I left out the condition for 'a'. I am also unsure how to include 'a' inside the Plot3D function.

Comment: Do you think it should yield all plots for $0\leq a\leq10$?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but since  0≤a≤10 is being stated I thought it should be included in the plotting function although I don't think it's important to do so at all. I tried to plot without including it and nothing appeared. So I included  0≤a≤10 and it's the same- no graph at all.

Comment: `f` is a function of **three** variables, i.e., `f[a_, x_, y_] = Cos[x + y] + Sin[a (x - y)];`

Answer (score 1):

```
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[Cos[x + y] + Sin[a (x - y)], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
  ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {a, 0, 
  10}]
```

Answer (score 0):

First use the right brackets in the functiondefinition

```
f [x_, y_] := Cos[x + y] + Sin[ a (x - y)]
```

Now it's possible to plot the function for special parameter `a->1`

```
Plot3D[f[x, y] /. a -> 1, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10},AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel]
```

[image]